# VBA custom password protecting for more than 1 sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a macro enabled excel sheet, with multiple tabs (there are 9 tabs I would like to do this on, but for the purposes of the question I'll include only 2), and for each tab I would like to add a password prompt that matches what I specify in the code.

This is working ok, but my issue is that when two sheets are located next to each other on the actual worksheets tab, it will go through them both rather than hiding the first one until i input the correct password.

For example, on my sheet I have a tab named Cascada, followed by a tab named Cascada2. If I were to put a blank tab inbetween these two, then my code would work correctly. However when they are in sequence, it seems to go through the sequence of password prompts regardless of whether I input the correct string or not.

See code below, any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

***EDIT UPDATED WITH ANSWER***

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim cascada As String, cascada2 As String
cascada = "Config_Cascada"
Rhea = "Config_Rhea"

Select Case Sh.Name
    Case cascada, cascada2

        Dim pwd As String
        pwd = "cascada" & IIf(Sh.Name = cascada2, 2, "")

        Dim Response As String
        Response = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")

        If Response = pwd Then
            Sh.Select
        Else
        Worksheets("Doors").Activate
        End If


End Select

Select Case Sh.Name
    Case Rhea

        Dim pwdRhea As String
        pwdRhea = "rhea"

        Dim ResponseRhea As String
        ResponseRhea = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")

        If Response = pwdRhea Then
            Sh.Select
        Else
        Worksheets("Doors").Activate
        End If


End Select

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot. Cleaner and works as far as I tested:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim cascada As String, cascada2 As String
    cascada = "config_Cascada"
    cascada2 = "config_Cascada2"

    Select Case Sh.Name
        Case cascada, cascada2

            Dim pwd As String
            pwd = "cascada" & IIf(Sh.Name = cascada2, 2, "")

            Dim Response as String
            Response = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")

            If Response = pwd Then
                Sh.Select
            End If

    End Select

    Application.EnableEvents = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your code works perfectly when putting in the right password, however if you put in the wrong password it seems to delete the sheet entirely, even when closing and reopening, it is still not there. I've had to load a backup and test it a few times. I also would like to scale this to the 9 or so sheets I have in the document, which won't all contain the string cascada in them. Thanks.

Comment: see now. i made a small change. there's no need to hide/unhide the sheet

Comment: Ok thanks, see edited OP. I added one piece to your code which redirects me to a "home" page if they put in the incorrect password, the last thing i want to do now is scale this to the 9 or so sheets i mentionned in my opening post. For example I could have another tab called "config_KitDrws" which I want the password to be "KitDrws" for. What would be the best way to do this? To separate out my case statements and add each password that I want?

Comment: I answered myself a bit, see OP for solution to this, not sure if it's best practice but it works well.

Comment: @Macca424 - by doing what you did you butchered the entire SO experience. You asked a question then edit your question with your own answer. That is *not at all helpful* to someone coming behind you. On top of that you added features to the original question, thus essentially, adding a question. Lastly, if the answer provided answered your question, it's best practice to mark it as answered.

Comment: Perhaps I should have added my answer to the comments which is fair, but the question and therefore answer would certainly be helpful to people coming behind me, many people relate to the question asked, then check the answer for code relevant to them. Adding features directly related to the question, also allowing the user to move away from having to name every sheet the same thing ? Then answering it myself - which I think again would help anyone coming behind me. Anyway, we're getting stuck in semantics here, thanks for the help, and hope others find it useful too..

Comment: @Macca424 - the problem is that you got rid of your original code that related to the question. By updating the question with the working code, anyone coming after can no longer see what the original problem is :)